# Navigation Drawer header Image blur

Tags: android, image, android-layout, blur

Hi I am trying to create a blurred image from a JSON Object URL, and set it as background to a RelativeLayout, but now I dont know how to do it :(

I want to to look like this image here:

[image]

And right now It looks like this:

[image]

My **fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_nav_drawer">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/blue">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
        android:textColor="@color/background_grey_light"
        android:text="Email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/background_grey_light"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/settingsicon"
        android:src="@string/fa_cog"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_container"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

My **FragmentDrawer.java (onCreateView)**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    // Fetching user details from SQLite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    final String apiKey = user.get("apiKey");

    // Making json object request

    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,
            AppConfig.API_URL + "/myprofile", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        String name = response.getString("name");
                        String email = response.getString("email");
                        String profileImgURL = response.getString("profileimg");

                        CircleImageView showProfileImg = (CircleImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                        TextView txtProfileName = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
                        TextView txtProfileEmail = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
                        txtProfileName.setText(name);
                        txtProfileEmail.setText(email);

                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(profileImgURL)
                                .into(showProfileImg);

                        RelativeLayout ProfilePicBg = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_header_container);

                        //ProfilePicBg = BitmapUtils.fastblur(ProfilePicBg, scaled, BLUR_RADIUS);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", apiKey);
            return headers;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}
```

And I Created a java file in my project with this fastblur java in Utils folder:

```
public class BitmapUtils {
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

public static Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, float scale, int radius) {

    int width = Math.round(sentBitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    int height = Math.round(sentBitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    sentBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sentBitmap, width, height, false);

    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    if (radius < 1) {
        return (null);
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    int wm = w - 1;
    int hm = h - 1;
    int wh = w * h;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    int r[] = new int[wh];
    int g[] = new int[wh];
    int b[] = new int[wh];
    int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
    int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

    int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divsum *= divsum;
    int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divsum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int[] sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
    int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
            sir = stack[i + radius];
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
            rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rsum];
            g[yi] = dv[gsum];
            b[yi] = dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw += w;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        yp = -radius * w;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

            sir = stack[i + radius];

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

            rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += w;
            }
        }
        yi = x;
        stackpointer = radius;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
            pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
            }
            p = x + vmin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[stackpointer];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi += w;
        }
    }

    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    return (bitmap);
}
}
```